# EF ADO.NET Issues with VS 2013 Ultimate

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, razor, webmatrix

Is anybody else having problems with EF ADO.NET and Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate right now? The entire thing is completely screwed.

I can't create any new websites and connect to a remote sql server (or local sdf database (sql ce)) using EF anymore. It's just stopped working. I've posted several questions for which I have had no response and Searching online for weeks on end hasn't helped a single bit. I've just about had enough of this. Not only are they dropping support for SQL CE sdf databases but now I can't even counter that by connecting to a remote database.

This question is not "how do I fix...", I've given up on that and have chosen a more reliable alternative. This question is: Is this a common issue that hasn't been resolved yet?

Comment: By stopped working... does that mean designer doesn't work, it won't connect to the DB with consistent errors, what?  Please add some specifics.

Comment: @BrianMains original issue was ".NET Framework Provider could not be found" when I tried debugging after adding EF/ADO.NET to it. I've literally visited 40~ web pages from google and not a single one of the solutions has helped. This problem seems to be linked with newer versions of _something_ (either VS or EF or WebPages) because I can still open up old solutions I wrote about 20 months ago )written in the exact same way, too) and they will work. I just can't create anything new anymore.

Comment: @BrianMains also, everything has been installed and referenced. Yet I continue to receive this "Data Provider could not be found" error. VS is also telling me that System.Data is already referenced when I try to add it to the bin folder but it isn't already referenced (which is why I'm trying to reference it). It's not in the bin folder and it's not in the Web.config file or anywhere else. I did a Find on the entire solution for "System.Data" and not a single result showed up.

Comment: System.Data is most likely already referenced.  View your proj file.

Comment: @spike.y - Since your rant doesn't contain any useful information, there's no way to know much of anything.  However, given the fact that older projects seem to work fine, it would seem that you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Do you get an error message? You don't really provide any information, so it's impossible to guess whether you broke VS with a bad addin, have some bad code, or whatever. I suggest you create a new simple project from scratch, just to ensure that your installation isn't broken due to something you installed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your connection string has the providerName attribute of System.Data.:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyDBEntities.csdl|res://*/MyDBEntities.ssdl|res://*/MyDBEntities.msl;provider=..." 
        providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```